# Where is the local help in Netbeans 9

Tags: netbeans-9

Win64 7/10
Netbeans 9.0

Netbeans 8.2 has a local Help (Help->Help Contents). Netbeans 9.0 only has an online help (Help->Online Docs & Support). The online help is near to useless, while the local help is very useful.

Is there any way to get a local help for Netbeans 9.0?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no local help available with NetBeans 9.0.

Given the timelines and effort required to migrate from Oracle NetBeans 8.2 to Apache NetBeans 9.0, providing online help is a feature that was excluded.

That said, I think it is unfortunate that the user is given no feedback at all. It would have fairly simple to display a popup stating "*Online help not implemented in this release*" rather than having absolutely nothing happen when the user clicks the **Help** button.

Additionally I think the limitation should have been formally documented; users don't expect functionality to be removed without warning when they upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. My concern is that the effort to make Java, et l., a cost center has made it 'attractive' to provide little useful help and replace it with the 'convenience' of paying for the same. My thought is that the NB 8.2 help files could have easily migrated with little change. But, what do I know.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Perhaps there was a legal reason that the help files couldn't be migrated. That was certainly the reason for other notable omissions in NetBeans 9.0 such as formal support for C++ and PHP. It's not simply a matter of copying some files from Oracle to Apache and tweaking them; even though I don't think any money changes hands between Oracle and Apache, lawyers are definitely involved in the process. (Just speculation on my part.)